# Showing android.support.v7.widget.SearchView at right align

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview, gravity

I'm trying to move the SearchView to the right on the toolbar but it's not working. Here is how I set the alignment in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {       
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    searchView.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));

    return true;
}
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Here is a demo image which shows how the SearchView currently appears:

[image]

Comment: menu items by default are right aligned. . are you talking about when you expand it you want it right aligned ?

Comment: i want my menu item icon should be right align

Comment: if i change my menu.xml app:show action as      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" than it default showing search icon as right but after click it will set as center as like showing in screen shot.

Comment: This is the default behavior of search view in toolbar and i think its not possible to align right though it was possible for actionbar and not using v7 searchview. One possible solution could be to use custom Toolbar.

Comment: ok so you mean i have to create custom searchview and set it to with toolbar right?

Comment: Yes. By default it will be right aligned . When expanded icon woll be left aligned. why do you need to align it right when expanded?

Comment: i need it to force it right aligned and cancel icon should be as left but my searchview icon must be at right align its pre requirement.

Comment: Then you need to customize toolbar.